# Route group namespace in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, frameworks, backend, laravel-routing, laravel-8

Im trying to defining namespace in laravel

old ver

```
Route::group('namespace' => 'RoleA'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index']);
    // call RoleA/HomeController
});
```

laravel 8

```
use App\Http\Controllers\RoleA\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RoleB\HomeController;
// return error => HomeController already in use

Route::group('namespace' => 'RoleA'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
    // call RoleA/HomeController
});

Route::group('namespace' => 'RoleB'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
    // still call RoleA/HomeController
});
```

is there another way or a correct way to use namespace in Laravel 8?

Edit, sorry for the ambigous question

I mean like the old version, when defining namespace
similar like this, or see the old version above

```
Route::group('namespace' => 'RoleB'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [RoleB/HomeController::class, 'index']);
    // will call RoleB/HomeController
});
```

is there a way to achieve something similar like code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think laravel drop the feature, because in laravel 8, controller will be Object oriented class

Laravel Routing 7.* Docs.

[image: Laravel Routing 7.* Docs.]

Laravel Routing 8.* Docs.

[image: Laravel Routing 8.* Docs.]

Comment: You can see in the doc "Namespace delimiters and slashes in URI prefixes are automatically added where appropriate" https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Comment: @Mtkz would you elaborate with example please?, i can grab the meaning clearly

Answer (score 2):

For the return error, import the controllers as follow (You cannot import same-named classes. So you should alias the name)

```
use App\Http\Controllers\RoleA\HomeController as HomeControllerA;
use App\Http\Controllers\RoleB\HomeController as HomeControllerB;
```

Then you can create route groups as [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes)

```
Route::prefix('RoleA')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // Matches The "/RoleA" URL
    });
});
```

You can use namespace as follow

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'HomeControllerA'], function()
{
    Route::get('/RoleA', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
}
```

Comment: how about namespace, is there a way to use namespace in Laravel 8, or is it not needed now?

Answer (score 0):

Import the controllers as follow -

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TestController as TestControllerAdmin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Employee\TestController as TestControllerEmployee;

Route::group(["prefix"=>"admin"], function(){
    Route::get('index',  [TestControllerAdmin::class, 'index']);
});
Route::group(["prefix"=>"employee"], function(){
    Route::get('index',  [TestControllerEmployee::class, 'index']);
});
```